# Image does not render on FlatList in some android devices

Tags: android, image, react-native, render, react-native-flatlist

It does not render in some android like moto g4 and samsung a50 !! It renders perfectly in some Android devices and iOS. When users try to open the app the images is not rendered as supposed to.

React Native version:

```
System:
    OS: macOS 10.15.1
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770HQ CPU @ 2.20GHz
    Memory: 943.08 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.12.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.13.0 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 13.1, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 16, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28
      Build Tools: 23.0.1, 25.0.0, 25.0.2, 26.0.0, 26.0.1, 26.0.2, 27.0.3, 28.0.2, 28.0.3
      System Images: android-16 | Intel x86 Atom, android-16 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-22 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-23 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-24 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-25 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-26 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-27 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
      Android NDK: 16.0.4293906-beta1
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.5900203
    Xcode: 11.1/11A1027 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0 
    react-native: 0.61.2 => 0.61.2 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    create-react-native-app: 2.0.2
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1
    react-native-git-upgrade: 0.2.7
    react-native-progress-circle: 2.0.0
```

Steps To Reproduce (my code)

```
<View style={{flex:1,width:'100%',height:'100%'}}>     
  <View style={{flex:1, height:'100%',backgroundColor:'#fff', paddingBottom:0}}>
    <ScrollView removeClippedSubviews={true} style={{padding:10,flex:1}} refreshControl={(<RefreshControl refreshing={this.state.refreshing} onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}/>)}>
      <View style={{marginBottom:30}}>
        <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold',color:'#000',fontSize:24}}>{feed.title}</Text>
        <FlatList
          removeClippedSubviews={true} 
          style={{marginTop:10,flexDirection:'column'}}
          data={feed.content}
          horizontal={true}
          keyExtractor={(item,index) => index}
          renderItem={({item,index}) => {
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity style={{marginBottom:15,flexBasis: '100%',flex:1}} onPress={()=>{this.contentOnPress(item)}}>
                <View style={{alignItems: 'center',width:width,height:this.height*0.6,borderRadius:5}}>
                  <Image resizeMode={'cover'} style={{width:width, height:(this.height*0.6), borderRadius:5,borderWidth:1,borderColor:'#ccc'}} resizeMode={'cover'} source={(item.thumb ? {uri: item.thumb.replace('upload/','upload/q_auto,w_auto/')} : require('./../../assets/img/profile-pic.png'))}/>
                </View>
                <View>
                  <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold',color:'#000'}} numberOfLines={1}>{item.header}</Text>
                  <Text style={{color:'#000'}} numberOfLines={1}>{item.title}</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        }} />
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
</View>
```

Comment: It would be great if regenerated your issue in https://snack.expo.io/

Comment: try it by giving some static height to `<Image>` component. Later on you can debug it easily if that works.

Comment: @Ravi , the images do have height

Comment: Can you remove the resizeMode={'cover'} and see if this makes the images appear on all devices? I had an issue with resizeMode cover when using Flatlists on android.

Comment: @needsleep it does not fix the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is specific on `Android pie (9)` when not using `https`. In my case all the urls are `http` which cause the problem.

The solution below url `http` can be used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
    </application>
</manifest>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

I fixed by replacing `http` with `https`

details here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24720

In this case `react-native-fast-image` and `removeClippedSubviews` are not necessary.

Comment: congratulations :)  and thank you for your sharing, it's very useful information for me too. i want to ask you a question, you said "it doesn't render moto g4". i know that it's android 6.0 by default, isn't it? are you sure about that's spesific on android pie?

Comment: @KubilayKiymaci Yes, I am. That's exactly the problem. The images are not rendered. The images get blank. You can see here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24720#issuecomment-566346324

Comment: maybe i had a mistake while i was asking my question . but i mean that it is an issue which is spesific on anroid 9 or under the android 9? for instance, we can see that problem android 5,6,7 or 9?

Comment: In my case only android 9 (pie) and maybe higher Android 5, 6, 7.. does not happen

Answer (score 6):

Try using [react-native-fast-image](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image) which will cache images and renders very fast.

Comment: I already tried it seems to solve the problem but my app depends on codepush which breaks if I release a new update with new lib.

Comment: I moved to react-native-fast-image lib I'm gonna test it in production . It working I check as acceptable answer..

Comment: What you can do is download the necessary images for use and delete it later on, we had some problems with images and devices like that before and sometimes the problem was inside fast image.
Have you tried to use the onError callback inside image?

Comment: It does not fix the problem

Answer (score 2):

there can be a lot of reasons.

1- can you try to delete "`removeClippedSubviews={true}`" prop.

2- maybe it's a performance problem. have you ever tried maxToRenderPerBatch prop of flatlist?

3- have you ever tried extraData prop of flatlist? you can use like this: `extraData={this.state}`

Comment: 1 - it didn't work
2 - didn't tried yet
3 - it didn't work

Comment: Did it work for you? I was avoiding the react-native-fast-image lib

Comment: i haven't tried it before with image component, but i had some performance problem with flatlist on some of android devices. especially, maxToRenderPerBatch prop was very useful for me and fixed my performance problem.